# jQuery fetch data from DB and iterate each array element to show in template

Tags: jquery

For my project, i am creating a view comments section for each picture uploaded by user. For that, i am fetching the details for all comments for a picture using ajax call and displaying the same in html. 
Also, i am submitting the form manually through post method and the function shows refreshed data after post.

Now, i have fetched two arrays , array contains the comment and array2 contains the user. Both are in order, so array[i] said array2[i] should display the comment by a user.

Example data for one picture.:

```
   ["go358938", "raman", "go358938", "go358938", "go358938", "go358938", "go358938", "go358938"]
```

and

```
["Wow", "Nice !", ":P", "Great !", "yes", "no", "what", "cute"]
```

Now i would like to show the same over to my html but below issue came. 
When i click view comments for any picture, it shows last entry of array[i] said array[i] in all the pictures, depending upon the number of objects in the array of each picture.
For eg. if first picture had 8 comments and second had 3 comments. Then on clicking view comments of second i see the last comment printed 3 times in second picture and same 8 times in first picture so on with all other pictures.

HTML:

```
          <div class="show">
          <a  href=""><h6>View Comments</h6></a>
            <div id="refresh" class="menu" style="display:none;">
              {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
                <div class="paraone" data-id="{{item.pk}}" style="margin:0;">
                  <div class="result">
                  </div>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="formtwo" method="post" action="">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <input data-id={{item.pk}} autocomplete="off"  type="text" name="commentadd" class="form-control" id="commentinput"  placeholder="Add Comment">
              </div>
              <div>
                <input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var iden,array,array2;
 function getdata(a) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'fetchertwo' %}",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      'search': iden
    },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
     array=data.content;
     array2 = data.author;
      console.log(array);
      console.log(array2);
      $.each(array, function(i, item) {
        $('.paraone').find(".result").append(array[i]  + array2[i])
          console.log(array[i], array2[i]);
          });
        }

     });
    }
   $('.show').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).find('.menu').toggle("slide");
   iden = $(this).find('.paraone').data('id');
   getdata(iden);
     $('.paraone').find(".result").html("")
   });
   $('#formtwo').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!iden){
     iden =  $(this).find('.form-control').data('id');
    }
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    var posting = $.post("/usercreation/picomment/" + iden, formData, 
    function(response) {getdata(iden);});
    this.reset();


   });
  });
```

Django View:

```
def fetchertwo(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    list=[]
    list2=[]
    name = Profilecomment.objects.filter(post=ImageLib.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('search', None)));
    for i in name:
        list.append(i.author)
    for j in name:
        list2.append(j.text)
    print(list)
    print(list2)
    data = {
    'content': list,
    'author':list2,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: how can i rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem `$('.paraone').find(".result").append(array[i] + array2[i]);` you are setting every element with the class of result to the combined values at that index, so it makes sense that all of them have the last value, to fix this, you can do this, edit, index the collection of elements with class `.paraone`:

```
   //.find() returns a jquery object which contains references to the dom elements, so theoretically, you should have the same amount of 
   //elements with className result as what you have in the array, so you can use the same 
   //index to set the specific element at that index
   //Since you get all comments as an array for the picture, use another for loop inside your iterating of the .each:
    for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
        $($($('.paraone')[i]).find('.result')[i]).append(array[j] + array2[j]);
    }
```

Comment: this seems to be partially working, now the data is coming perfectly, however, all the picture comments for any picture come under the section of the first post only. Can you help with that ?

Comment: Sorry bud, its keeping the same problem i commented above and only printing the last comment of each picture.

Comment: WHich array holds the comments?

Comment: Array 2 holds them

Comment: @GovindShah How do you know which comments go with which picture? Since you are just passing the comments back as an array of strings...

Comment: On the click action,  i call getdata func with iden as the parameter. Iden is what ive passed from html to jquery. This iden is basically the image object in my db. Based on this image object i search the db for related Comments through an ajax call to my django view. That django view returns me the arrays in a dict. So whenever i click on view comments of a picture, im basically passing the image object id and fetching the user and comment in the form of arrays.

Comment: @GovindShah Updated answer again.

Comment: Bud, still the same issue, on the click of view comments of any picture, shows the comments in the first pictures section only.

Comment: Like i click on the second picture, and the comments get loaded on first.

Comment: @GovindShah Ok. I'll see if I can fix this.

Comment: @GovindShah What is the value of `iden` in your I understand it is an identity column for choosing the photo in ajax, is there anyway to use this value to identify which div with class .paraone to append comment to?